# Google Sheets, random text cell from column, but not used in last 7 selections

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, spreadsheet, google-sheets-api

I have a Google sheet where I am pulling in the weather from a BBC RSS feed. (weather tab). I am then extracting the current brief weather synopsis from the title, so 'Sunny' for example.

I want to have 10 or so messages (Select Tab) in a column labelled 'Sunny' (there's Rain, Cloudy and others too) where a random cell is selected based on today's weather, and then sent to the 'Todays Message' sheet 
So I need to say basically. If Weather!A5 = :Sunny, then select a random message from !Select A:A (but not that's been used in the last 7 times) and paste a copy to !Todays_Message A5.

I hope that makes some kind of sense?

Here's the sheet and it's opened up for editing:
[Google Sheet Test](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/11okjbrUZnVttkElmnwzXZVZl2_Mp2Vk32IdEKaYV3fk/edit?usp=sharing)

Thanks in advance

Comment: What did you tried? Did you already considered to use the built-in functions random() or randbetween()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've made [sample test file](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1lCZR7TBdBcYt0INyhutBheYvcVMxmrH7vXPpGxQwrNg/edit?usp=sharing) for you.

[image]

In order to simplify formulas, I've pasted all the data in one sheet:

- `A1:D1` -- list of possible weathers (:Sunny, :Mostly Cloudy, :Cloudy, :Rain)
- `A2:D11` -- list of messages
- `F2:F8` -- last 7 selections
- `H2` -- current weather

First task is to find list of possible messages, they must contain comments for current weather, but not contain last 7 messages.

The formula, pasted in cell H8 is:

```
=FILTER(OFFSET(A1,1,MATCH(H2,A1:D1,0)-1,10),
REGEXMATCH(OFFSET(A1,1,MATCH(H2,A1:D1,0)-1,10),join("|",F2:F8))=false)
```

This is *list of possible messages*

And the formula in H4:

```
=INDEX(H8:H,RANDBETWEEN(1,COUNTA(H8:H)))
```

It will pick random item from *list of possible messages*

---

**Update**

I've added sheet "All Messages" and list of them in range "A2:A". The formula to find *last 7 messages* is:

```
=QUERY({ArrayFormula(row(OFFSET('All Messages'!A2,,,counta('All Messages'!A2:A)))),
OFFSET('All Messages'!A2,,,counta('All Messages'!A2:A))},
"select Col2 order by Col1 desc limit 7 ")
```

It is placed in cell F2 is sample file.

Comment: One quick question, is there anyway to automate the process of the last 7 messages at all?

Comment: I've added this into sample file. formula to find last 7 messages is `=QUERY({ArrayFormula(row(OFFSET('All Messages'!A2,,,counta('All Messages'!A2:A)))),OFFSET('All Messages'!A2,,,counta('All Messages'!A2:A))},"select Col2 order by Col1 desc limit 7 ")`